# Migrate to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, localytics

I'm trying to migrate to AndroidX and we use this library in our project. However, this is currently causing an issue in our project:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':module@buildType/compileClasspath':
>   Failed to transform file 'localytics-1.3.0.aar' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform

Removing the library makes this issue disappear.
Is there any workaround that would allow me to migrate to AndroidX til this library is migrated?

Per the documentation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

I have updated my gradle.properties. The issue is not with setup, the issue is that localytics does not seem to support androidX. I want to confirm this if anyone knows since contacting them results in no answer (they have poor costumer service).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone posted a patch on [Github](https://github.com/segment-integrations/analytics-android-integration-localytics/issues/14):

1. Clone the repository.
2. Update the analytics-android-integration-localytics project to the latest
   Android updates, including AndroidX. Generate a jar file instead of
   an aar file. (This is the winning item here. It must be a jar file
   for it to work. An aar file isn't needed anyway since there aren't
   any resources in this project's aar file.)
3. Remove the existing maven dependencies in the consuming project.
4. Import the jar file as new module in the consuming project.
5. Rebuild the consuming project.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere! Man, that is a process though. I wish localytics would fix this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please add following line in gradle.properties

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

Can you please share your build.gradle ? May be there can have another issue. Please update the following localytics library like this.

classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'   to

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
```

Comment: I do not use fabric. My issue is with localytics.

Answer (score 1):

If jetfier is not working on that library, I think you can try some workarounds such as:

- Update the library (is v1.3.0 the latest version of that AAR?)
- Disable jetfier as a whole (setting `android.enableJetifier=false` on `gradle.properties`)
- Disable jetfier on that library only via:

on `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.jetifier.blacklist = .*localytics.*
android.useAndroidX=true
```

This last option requires Android Gradle Plugin version

Comment: Nice! I am going to try the blacklist option.

Comment: Still same results, also I am getting this warning: The option setting 'android.jetifier.blacklist=.*localytics.*' is experimental and unsupported

Comment: Really sorry to know about it. Googling, it seems a common issue with that library...